# MatLab code doesn't add values into the list within loop

Tags: list, matlab, loops, indexing

I have this code:

```
chl_data = ncread('L3m_20210901-20210930__420535409_4_GSM-MODVIR_CHL1_MO_00.nc', 'CHL1_mean');
round_values=[];
TF = isnan(chl_data);
chl_data(TF)=0;
for kx = length(chl_data)
    for kz = size(chl_data,2)
        if chl_data(kx,kz)~=0
            round_values(kx,kz) = round(chl_data(kx,kz),1);
        end
    end
end
```

which supposed to add values into the empty list round_values, but it doesn't. Moreover, there is no any warnings after execution.

Comment: Your `for` loops will only execute once each. For example if `length(chl_data)` is 2000, the outer loop will execute once with `kx` equal to 2000. Did you mean to use `for kx = 1:length(chl_data)`, etc?

Comment: OMG, you're right! Missed that. Everything is working now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool. Why not just get rid of the loops and do `round_values = round(chl_data, 1);` though?

Comment: Well, the loop needs to be in order to deal with other task, so I've just started with loop. But yes, I didn't see that simple solution for 'round'. Thank you so much)